Running out of RAM when finetuning model
I am currently trying to finetune Wav2Vec2 model from: https://huggingface.co/dima806/bird_sounds_classification. But my RAM utilisation is running over the free tier on Google Colab.
The following is my code:
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer

# Load model with ignore_mismatched_sizes=True
model = Wav2Vec2ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "dima806/bird_sounds_classification",
    num_labels=len(label2id),
    ignore_mismatched_sizes=True
)

# Set up training with gradient accumulation
batch_size = 1  # Reduce batch size to manage memory
accumulation_steps = 4  # Accumulate gradients over 4 steps

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=accumulation_steps,  # Gradient accumulation
    num_train_epochs=3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    fp16=True,  # Enable mixed precision training
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    tokenizer=feature_extractor,
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()

What could be the reasons the RAM is going past 12.7GB? My dataset only contains 20 items. How can I address this issue?

how long are your sounds ? its not just the number of items in your dataset that matters also whats in it has an effect

@KaranShishoo hey! Thanks for the comment, I have resolved it, it is indeed the length of the sounds that were too long, breaking the audio into chunks resolved the issue

The sound inputs were too long, after resampling the audio into chunks, the problem was resolved.
